# Replace only first row for each user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table that has users, food, and which one is their favorite.

| user | food | is_favorite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beef | False |
| 1 | Pork | False |
| 3 | Pork | False |
| 3 | Beef | False |
| 3 | Potatoes | False |
| 4 | Beef | False |

The same user appears in several rows. I need to set exactly 1 of the rows *per user* as favorite (`is_favorite`=True):

| user | food | is_favorite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beef | True |
| 1 | Pork | False |
| 3 | Pork | True |
| 3 | Beef | False |
| 3 | Potatoes | False |
| 4 | Beef | True |

Now every user has exactly 1 favorite food.

---

I successfully got exactly 1 row for each user, but can't apply it to my initial `df`. I'm pretty sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I don't know pandas that well. It also feels like this is the wrong way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        user=[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4],
        food=['Beef', 'Pork', 'Pork', 'Beef', 'Potatoes', 'Beef'],
        is_favorite=[False, False, False, False, False, False]))

# This works. It gives me exactly 1 row per user
first_food_per_user = df.groupby('user').nth(0).reset_index()

# This doesn't work
for _, row in first_food_per_user.iterrows():
    df['is_favorite'].loc[
        (df['user'] == row['user'])
        &
        df['food'] == row['food'],
    ] = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `groupby`, just use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[~df['user'].duplicated(), 'is_favorite'] = True
```

Output:

```
   user      food  is_favorite
0     1      Beef         True
1     1      Pork        False
2     3      Pork         True
3     3      Beef        False
4     3  Potatoes        False
5     4      Beef         True
```

If you want to set a random row use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
idx = df.groupby('user')['is_favorite'].sample(n=1).index
df.loc[idx, 'is_favorite'] = True
```

Example:

```
   user      food  is_favorite
0     1      Beef         True
1     1      Pork        False
2     3      Pork        False
3     3      Beef         True
4     3  Potatoes        False
5     4      Beef         True
```